# ¿Cómo obtener la media de una columna en función de otra en un CSV?

Tags: bash

Si tengo un fichero csv con el nombre de alumno seguido de una coma y su correspondiente nota:

```
Alumno1, 5
Alumno1, 7
Alumno2, 5
Alumno3, 6
```

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que me haga la media de ese alumno? (puede tener mas de una nota)

He intentado esto:

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS="," read Alumno Nota
do

# lo que quiero hacer aquí es: 
#   si el siguiente alumno es el mismo, suma la nota con las otras,
#   sino y al acabar, divide entre las notas que tiene y esa será su nota
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En Bash puedes realizar esta operación, pero se complica bastante porque hay que declarar todo explícitamente.

Por contra, Awk te ofrece todo esto de una forma mucho más ligera:

```
awk -F, '{alumno[$1]+=$2;notas[$1]++}
          END{for (a in alumno) print a, alumno[a]/notas[a]}' fichero
```

Aquí lo que hacemos es definir la coma como separador y, a partir de allí, mantener dos vectores: uno para la suma de notas de cada alumno y otro para la cantidad de notas que tiene cada uno. Finalmente es cuestión de recorrer el vector e ir calculando la media.

Con tu fichero:

```
$ awk -F, '{alumno[$1]+=$2;notas[$1]++} END{for (a in alumno) print a, alumno[a]/notas[a]}' fichero
Alumno1 6
Alumno2 5
Alumno3 6
```

Aquí

Comment: Disculpa, cuando haces alumno[$1]+=$2 ¿qué estás haciendo exactamente? Gracias.

Comment: @Julio dado el vector "alumno", cada elemento guarda el valor para un alumno dado. Por tanto, "alumno[Alumno1]" contiene la suma de notas de Alumno1, por ejemplo. Al hacer `+=` estamos añadiendo una nota al total.